# Unable to instantiate specified TransactionFactory class [org.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-ogm

I have a problem. I am new in hibernate and I want to write a very simple example with HibernateOGM. I get an Exception that says:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate specified TransactionFactory class [org.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory]*

I have searched really alot, but I couldn't find any solution for my problem. As I understand, the problem occures in this line:

```
sessionfactory=cfgogm.buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry);
```

If I comment the other lines I have no exception, only INFOS.

this is my Stacktrace:

```
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(TransactionFactoryInitiator.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.transaction.impl.OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.buildServiceInstance(OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.transaction.impl.OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.buildServiceInstance(OgmTransactionFactoryInitiator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OptionalServiceInitiator.initiateService(OptionalServiceInitiator.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
```

here you can find my code and hibernate.cfg.xml and pom.xml:

```
 OgmConfiguration cfgogm=new OgmConfiguration();
            cfgogm.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            serviceregistry=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfgogm.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionfactory=cfgogm.buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry)
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>  
  <session-factory>


    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">rcfdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate-contact.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>hogm</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateOGM_MongoDB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>HibernateOGM_MongoDB</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.2.1</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <goals>
                                  <goal>exec</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
  </build>

 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.0.Beta1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.0.Beta2</version>
     </dependency>   

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.11</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

could you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Object/Grid Mapper (OGM) is a persistence engine providing Java Persistence (JPA) support for **NoSQL** datastores. so why do you use **hibernate-ogm** with derby?

check out the [official guide for hibernate-ogm with mangoDB](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e1882)

--edit--

is there something like **JDBCTransactionFactory** in any of your configuration file? try remove it.

Comment: Sorryyy, I did a big mistake. I have pasted another `hibernate.cfg.xml` now I have updated my post, with this cfg.xml I have this problem

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: I put it in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property> and now I don't see the error, but another errors, I think I shoould write another post, thank you for your hint :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct class name is org.**hibernate**.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory.

Probably hibernate picks up some property or properties file with the incorrect classname.

If you can't find it, override it in your own hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property  name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
```